# read() returns EAGAIN after epoll reported EPOLLIN for timerfd

Tags: linux, timer, epoll

I use timerfd with `TFD_NONBLOCK` option.

This timer is added to epoll controller with only `EPOLLIN` event set.
If `EPOLLIN` occurs, `read()` is used on this timer.

In 99% cases everything works great. Execution stops on `epoll_wait`, then is continued after timer interval. However under heavy system load i received `EAGAIN` from `read()` a few times.

This looks like i receive `EPOLLIN` but then nothing is availible for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **probably** found an answer.

In my program I was using a few timers at once, some of them were modifying intervals of others. With little or no load epoll was executing single event at once. Under heavy load some events were queued and then executed in a loop. While processing the queue, if first event modified interval of next timer - it became 'not-ready'. But then loop proceeded to second timer, causing read() on not-ready-anymore timer.

Comment: After some time I can say - this WAS a solution :)